# Can't parent face rig to neck bones for test

Tags: rigging

Was trying to follow a video where he attached the root bone in super face rig to neck bones to rotate head. In edit mode I select the face rig but I cannot Shift-select the top bone of the neck rig (red check mark) to parent them together. The video shows it being done, but they don't explain how. Any help appreciated.
[image]

Comment: It would help to see the video (link?) Are you sure there are 2 armatures? You cannot parent a bone from one armature to another. This only works with a bone constraint. Or join both armatures first (Ctrl+J), then it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did have two separate armatures and was able to combine them and parent the face rig to the neck bones.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Blunder for the comment on my question.

I did have two separate armatures and was able to combine them and parent the face rig to the neck bones.

Comment: Hope you don't mind the edit. You can click the tick on your own answer to mark the question as cleared up.